# rails how to access custom input form field

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Hello i have nested form and i need to access my own input tag after submit in model via function

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :address, :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:city].blank? }
```

I have User form and Address form is nested, i add checkbox to the form. How can i access it ?

example:

```
    <%= f.label :telephone %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :telephone %>

<input type="checkbox" id="addAddress"/> Fill Address
<%= f.fields_for :address do |builder| %>

    <%= builder.label :name, "Name" %><br />
    <%= builder.text_field :name, :disabled => true %>
```

I need access checkbox status via lambda function, is it possible? thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an accessor like this in your model:

```
attr_accessor :add_address
```

and in your form:

```
<%= f.check_box :add_address %>
```

then in your lambda you can check the value of `add_address`

Comment: Hello thank you i think it will work if in nested form i will have that checkbox, but checkbox is in main form.. so how can i check them in my model ? i have
`accepts_nested_attributes_for :address, :reject_if => !user.add_address` but it does not work, thank you

Comment: If i use 
`accepts_nested_attributes_for :address, :reject_if => lambda { !user.add_address }
accepts_nested_attributes_for :company, :reject_if => lambda { !user.add_company }`
after submit it shows me an error 
`Can't mass-assign protected attributes: add_address, add_company (im using 2 similar nested forms)`

Comment: okay i just have it.. i needed add :add_address to attr_accessible and nested_att looks like this `accepts_nested_attributes_for :address, :reject_if => !:add_address`